# Mobile-safari private browsing local storage error but no code is calling it

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, mobile-safari, aem

I'm working on a page that's hosted via Adobe CQ5 (now AEM).

The page rendered is a .JSP file that also has Java, HTML and Javascript code on it.

I'm rendering a series of logos, and they are displaying totally fine on all browsers except mobile-safari in private browsing. That's yielding me the error in console of:

```
 QuotaExceededError: Dom exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota
```

Researching around, it appears in private browsing in iOS7 local storage is turned off.

However, none of my code calls local storage. I'm trying to figure out if local storage is the culprit here.

I have some Java code that assembles a StringBuffer of the brand list.

```
 String cssClassPrefix = "svg-icon-";
 String cssClass = "";
 StringBuffer brandJsonObject = new StringBuffer();
 String externalPrefix = "";

 if(currentNode.hasProperty("brands")){

   Property prop = currentNode.getProperty("brands");

   if(prop.isMultiple()){
      Value[] brandArray = prop.getValues();
      for(Value brand : brandArray) {
            if(brandJsonObject.length() != 0){
            brandJsonObject.append(", ");
        }
        cssClass = cssClassPrefix + brand.getString().toLowerCase();
        brandJsonObject.append("{\"name\" : \""+brand.getString().toLowerCase()+"\", \"cssName\" : \""+cssClass+"\"}");
    }
}
```

I then parse that string as JSON and put it into a JS variable:

```
<script id="data" type="application/json"><%=brandJsonObject.toString() %></script>
var brandJSON = JSON.parse($("#data").html());
```

Then in a separate JS function, I iterate across the JSON object an display the html, I use the  element and it's data attribute:

```
function arrangeBrands () {

      // make all the json data into one long html string and put inside wraper via append()
var brand = rowElement;
$.each(brandJSON, function(i,n){
          brand += '<div class="span2' /* + (bootstrapSpan) */ +' brandItem brandItemStatic"><object data="/etc/designs/searshomeservices/clientlib_base/images/svg-company-logos/'+n["name"]+'.svg" class="'+ n["cssName"]+' many"><img src="/etc/designs/searshomeservices/clientlib_base/images/svg-company-logos/'+n["name"]+'.png" alt="'+ n["name"] +'" /></object></div>';
});
```

My question is, does any of this utilize local storage and thus give me that issue I'm seeing iOS7 mobile-safari private browsing? I'm not explicitly calling localStorage anywhere, but I'm not sure. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because CQ uses localstorage in their clientlibs, it builds a shared.js file.
Here you can find the hotfix from Adobe:

http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cq561-available-hotfixes.html

10-Jun-2014 NPR-4107    Private browsing on Safari produces QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR